# How can I match up crypto held and price in reference asset (e.g. USDT) Binance API

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api, binance

Some background: I'm a long-time advanced user of excel/googlesheets now beginning in python for data analysis and manipulation.  First-time posting too...here's to a barmy future & apologies if this not the right platform.

I am using Binance AP to calculate update values for my portfolio.  I use get_account for specific assets held (i.e. BTC) and prices retrieved with get_all_tickers, but these have a trading-pair (i.e BTCUSDT).  I would like to lookup the USDT token pairing matching each of my assets and return a dataframe to summarise and create a piechart.

````
```    # get balances for all assets & some account information
info = client.get_account()
bal = info['balances']
myBal = []

for b in bal:
    if float(b['free']) >0 or float(b['locked']) >0:
        myBal.append(b)

df = pd.DataFrame(myBal)

prices = client.get_all_tickers()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(prices)

df3 = df2[df2["symbol"].str.contains("USDT")].sort_values(by="symbol")
````

```
Example of assets structure output is like:
[{'asset': 'BTC', 'free': '1.00000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'},
 {'asset': 'ETH', 'free': '2.00000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'},
 {'asset': 'USDT', 'free': '3.00000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'},
 {'asset': 'XRP', 'free': '4.00000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'}]

Example of prices structure output is like:
[{'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'price': '0.07078900'},
 {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'price': '0.00282300'},
 {'symbol': 'BNBETH', 'price': '0.13560000'},
 {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '38966.01000000'},
 {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '2758.36000000'},
 {'symbol': 'HSRBTC', 'price': '0.00041400'}]

Structure of the desired output would be:
[{'asset': 'BTC', 'free': '1.00000000', 'locked': '0.00000000','price': '38966.01000000'}]
```

I can get base data and have them in separate dataframes; my spreadsheet-visual background is to audit the steps and continually debug the process.

1. am I overcomplicating by using dataframes and
2. is there a better-faster way to manipulate and combine in code before generating a final dataframe?

Comment: Have you tried using [pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/)?

Comment: Not used that, looks way ahead of me.  I'm taking babysteps to grasp fundamentals of lists and dataframes.  Thanks for the suggestion though.